# Can't connect other services when running docker image that is built from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a node project which uses Redis for queue purposes.
I required the Redis in compose file & it's working fine. But when I try to build the docker image from the Dockerfile and run that built image with `docker run`, it can't find/connect to the Redis.
My question is: **If docker doesn’t include the images from the compose file when building the image from Dockerfile, how the built image can run?**

Compose & Dockerfile are given below.

```
version: '3'
services:
  oaq-web:
    image: node:16.10-alpine3.13
    container_name: oaq-web
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/oaq
    networks:
      - oaq-network
    working_dir: /usr/src/oaq
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    command: npm run dev
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - oaq-network
networks:
  oaq-network:
    driver: bridge
```

```
FROM node:16.10-alpine3.13

RUN mkdir -p app

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Do you run the `docker run` command with the network cli switch? Like: `docker run --network <network_name>`

Comment: Things like mapping ports, setting environment variables and connecting to a network are done when you run an image, not when you build it. When you build an image from a `Dockerfile` with `docker build` the content of any potential `docker-compose.yml` is not relevant at all.

Comment: @super So when I'm building an image using Dockerfile & want to run it on my local/remote machine, I have to make sure that other required images/services listed in compose file are already running?

Comment: Copying the `docker-compose.yml` file over is probably the easiest way to do it.  You shouldn't normally need to copy anything else though.  (Delete especially the `volumes:` block.)